# getting error when building cordova project

Tags: android, cordova

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
>        Owner PID: unknown
>        Our PID: 45035
>        Owner Operation: unknown
>        Our operation: resolve configuration ':classpath'
>        Lock file: /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock

Comment: i think problem is Ur cordova version . can u try some lowest version? it ll be helpful for u.

Comment: how you build the android application ?